# Does Spark's Fair Scheduler pool provides inter- or intra-application scheduling?

Tags: apache-spark

I am quite confused,because these pools are getting created for each spark application, and also if I keep minshare for a pool greater than the total cores of the cluster, the pool got created.

So if these pools are intra application do I need to, assign different pools to different spark jobs manually, because if I use sparkcontext.setlocalproperty for setting the pool, then all the stages of that application goes to that pool.

Point is that can we have jobs from two different application, to go in the same pool, so if I have application a1 and used sparkcontext.(pool,p1), and other application a2 and used sparkcontext.(pool,p1), would jobs for both applocation will go to the same pool p1 or p1 for a1 is different from p1 for a2.

Comment: Read [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html). Also to answer your question the pools are created at **Cluster Manager**, so the applications/ jobs share the pool. 2 applications using same pool name will be in the same pool.

Comment: It means inter-application scheduling can be achieved by using fair scheduler pools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in Spark's official documentation in [Scheduling Within an Application](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#fair-scheduler-pools):

> Inside a given Spark application (SparkContext instance), multiple parallel jobs can run simultaneously if they were submitted from separate threads.

and later in the same document:

> Starting in Spark 0.8, it is also possible to configure fair sharing between jobs. Under fair sharing, Spark assigns tasks between jobs in a “round robin” fashion, so that all jobs get a roughly equal share of cluster resources. This means that short jobs submitted while a long job is running can start receiving resources right away and still get good response times, without waiting for the long job to finish. This mode is best for multi-user settings.

With that, the scheduling happens within resources given to a Spark application and how much it gets depends on CPUs/vcores and memory available in a cluster manager.

The Fair Scheduler mode is essentially for Spark applications with parallel jobs.